# Cocos2d-x Android build won't find extensions

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

During running build_native.py i get error `"ExtensionMacros.h" no such file or directory`.
The file itself is in cocos2d\extensions. I edited android.mk and uncommented line resposnsible for including this file. Why wont it find it? 
Here is my android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/external)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/cocos)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/extensions)

LOCAL_MODULE := cocos2dcpp_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libcocos2dcpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/Boxx.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/World.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/U.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/CarrerWorld.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/VisibleRect.cpp 

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocosdenshion_static

# LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += box2d_static
# LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocosbuilder_static
# LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += spine_static
# LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocostudio_static
# LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos_network_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos_extension_static


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,.)
$(call import-module,audio/android)

# $(call import-module,Box2D)
# $(call import-module,editor-support/cocosbuilder)
# $(call import-module,editor-support/spine)
# $(call import-module,editor-support/cocostudio)
# $(call import-module,network)
$(call import-module,extensions)
```

and the top of error source cpp file :

```
#include "World.h"
#include "U.h"
#include "Boxx.h"
#include "Globals.h"
#include "VisibleRect.h"
#include "extensions/cocos-ext.h"  //<---- this file includes "extensionMacros.h"  
USING_NS_CC;
USING_NS_CC_EXT;
```

Comment: what do you mean wrong tag? The files were auto generated(android.mk) I didn't add any  lines there

Answer (score 0):

Does cocos2d/extensions/Android.mk have the line?

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/..
```

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/extensions/Android.mk#L40

It needs to find the header file.

Comment: yes it does. I am still unable to fix this.

`LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/..

LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/.. \
                           $(LOCAL_PATH)/GUI/CCControlExtension \
                           $(LOCAL_PATH)/GUI/CCScrollView`

Comment: I imported project to eclipse and here is what i get:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/b70aaevdr7myb3t/Przechwytywanie.JPG

Comment: In that case, it should work well. cocos2d/extensions/ExtensionMacros.h actually exist?